# pandas dataframe groupby with all columns (but first) have string type

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfA=pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A','C','D'],
'assign':['R','R/W',''],
'create':['R/W','R','R']})
dfB=pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A','B','D','A'],
'points':['R/W','R','','-'],
'create':['-','R','R','R']})`
```

Задача проста, необходимо построчно сравнить два файла формата Excel по значению первой колонки. dfB необходимо сравнить с dfA . Сгруппировать по первой колонке и вывести значения всех остальных колонок только по строкам, содержащим измененные значения (т.е. строка со значением "D" не выводится). Правила:

1. если колонка имеется в двух таблицах (кроме первой), то выводим    историю изменений (значения из dfB через разделитель "_" значения из dfA ),
2. если колонка имеется только в dfB (нет в dfA), то выводим значения    без разделителя (кроме повторяющихся строк в dfB) ,
3. если колонка имеется только в dfA (нет в dfB), то выводим в конце списка без разделителя (кроме повторяющихся строк в dfA)

Result must be:

```py
`dfC=pd.Dataframe({'team': ['A','B','C'],
'points':[['R/W,'-'],'R',''],
'create':[['-','R','R/W'],'R','_R'],
'assign':['R','_','_-']})
```

объединяем две таблицы, вторую с первой по внешнему соединению, чтобы последовательность колонок совпадала с dfB, а уникальные колонки из dfA были в конце

```py
dfC=pd.merge(dfB,dfA, how='outer')
```

как сравнить значения всех колонок по-отдельности, сгруппировав по первой колонке? Первое, что приходит на ум-это агрегация по заранее подготовленному в цикле списку колонок. Наверное можно проще.

```py
import pandas as pd
dfA=pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A','C','D'], 'assign':['R','R/W',''],'create':['R/W','R','R']})
dfB=pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A','B','D','A'], 'points':['R/W','R','','-'],'create':['-','R','R','R']})
# Объединяем две таблицы обязательно по внешнему соединению
dfC=dfB.merge(dfA, how='outer')
# display(dfC)
b_columns=dfB.columns[1:]
or_columns=set.union(set(dfA.columns[1:]),set(dfB.columns[1:]))
and_columns=set.intersection(set(dfB.columns[1:]),set(dfA.columns[1:]))
del_columns=set.difference(set(dfA.columns[1:]),set(dfB.columns[1:]))
add_columns=set.difference(set(dfB.columns[1:]),set(dfA.columns[1:]))
agg_columns={}
for i in list(b_columns):
    agg_columns[i] = lambda x: list(x)
# res=dfC.groupby('team').agg(list)
# Сворачиваем по первой колонке все значения по колонкам второй таблицы
res=dfC.groupby('team').agg(agg_columns).reset_index()
print(res)
```

И самое главное, я не знаю как правильно убрать строки, в которых не было изменений между колонками. Первое, что приходит на ум это цикл по колонкам dfB и использованием комбинации np.where

```py
for name, values in dfB.iteritems():
   v=np.where(values==dfA[name],0,1)
   if np.sum(v)>0:
```